# undefined symbol: cudnnCreate in ubuntu google cloud vm instance

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04, cudnn

I'm trying to run a tensorflow python script in a google cloud vm instance with GPU enabled. I have followed the process for installing GPU drivers, cuda, cudnn and tensorflow. However whenever I try to run my program (which runs fine in a super computing cluster) I keep getting:

> undefined symbol: cudnnCreate

I have added the next to my ~/.bashrc

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64"
>
> export CUDA_HOME="/usr/local/cuda-8.0"
> export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin"

but still it does not work and produces the same error

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: The issue was not that the library was not installed, the library installed was the wrong version hence it could not find it. In this case it was cudnn 5.0. However even after installing the right version it still didn't work due to incompatibilities between versions of driver, CUDA and cudnn. I solved all this issues by re-installing everything including the driver taking into account tensorflow libraries requisites.